# Vanishing Moments

Tags: wavelet

I am reading a book titled *"Two Dimensional Wavelets and their relatives"* by Antoine et al. and it talks about *vanishing moments*. I have trouble understanding the exact significance of it. Can anybody give an idea on vanishing moments?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could tell _which_ of the hundreds of papers on wavelets you are reading? and in what context the phrase "vanishing moment" is used?

Comment: I am reading a book titled "Two Dimensional Wavelets and their relatives" by Antoine et al. I have a pic of the exact place where I am referring to. Please find it here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28068989/IMAG0746.jpg

Comment: In brief, if a wavelet has $n$ vanishing moments, the output of filtering a $n$-th degree polynomial with this wavelet will be 0.

Comment: This is an intuitive explanation "for dummies" I don't know about continuous wavelets, but in discrete wavelets, a wavelet with $n$ vanishing moments, produce low coefficients on the parts of the data which can be approached by a polynomial with degree $n$. It facilitates the identification of parts of the data as "polynomial of order $n$" This should be a comment, and not an answer, but I'm not allowed to comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A moment is a generalization of the notion in physics of moment of a (point) mass about an axis being the product of the mass and the distance from the axis.

For a continuous random variable $X$ with probability density function $f(x)$, the $n$-th moment is 
$$m_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
The *zero-th* moment is $1$ (the area under the density is $1$),
the *first moment* is called the *mean* or expected value of the random 
variable and the *second moment* the mean square value.  Note that since
$f(x) \geq 0$, the second moment cannot be zero.

Even more generally, the  $n$-th moment of an *arbitrary* function $f(x)$
can be defined as 
$$m_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Now the restriction of zero-th moment being $1$ and
second moment being positive is not applicable any more, 
and the "vanishing moment" is merely
a fancy way of saying that $f(x)$ must be such that
$m_0 = m_1 = m_2 = \cdots m_N = 0$. In particular, $m_0$ is
the *DC value* of the wavelet and the authors are insisting
that the DC value be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

One of the applications of the (continuous!) wavelet transform is the detection and characterization of fractal signals. For that in particular the nature of the underlying singularities become important. Singularities are characterized by their Höldner exponent. In that context the number of vanishing moments of the analysis wavelet becomes important. It needs to have at least as many vanishing moments as the order of Höldner exponent to be discovered by it.